# How can I decide the exact value for some parameters in computer hardware?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, temperature, cpu-speed

I am using two apps; **Open Hardware Monitor** and **CPUID HWMinitor** for monitoring various parameters of Motherboard, Processor, Graphic Card and Hard Drive.

I noticed that value of a parameter in one app is different from another app. Sometimes it creates confusion. **Open Hardware Monitor** shows parameters values in two columns (*Value* & *Max*) and **CPUID HWMinitor** shows parameters values in three columns (*Value*, *Min* & *Max*).

For my query, I would like to take three parameters (CPU Fan Speed, CPU Temperature and Motherboard Temperature) as an example.

I believe *Value* means the exact value on real time and *Max* means it shouldn’t be beyond this value. *Max* value also changes.

How can I decide that temperature, speed, etc must not go beyond a fixed value for a Motherboard, Processor, Graphic Card and Hard Drive?

I hope I explained my query well.

Regards
John

Comment: "Max" is usually the maximum value **seen**, not necessarily the absolute maximum value possible.

Answer (score 1):

The max value indicates the maximum value that was encountered during the time the program was open. Likewise, the min value indicates the lowest value encountered. The actual current value will be displayed in the value column.

Finding the actual maximum temperatures for your components is not too difficult for CPUs and GPUs. I will list some examples but as you haven't mentioned your actual hardware, you'll have to do some searching yourself.

Intel usually mentions two different temperatures for their CPUs. One is the temperature measured in the package, outside the cores and the other is the temperature measured inside the actual cores of the CPU. More information can be found on the Intel website: [Temperature FAQ on intel.com](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005597/processors.html)

Nvidia also lists maximum temperatures for their cards. This goes for the actual GPU. Some graphics cards also have a separate sensor for the RAM or the power supply. Usually no maximum temperatures are listed for those parts but you can find some guidelines by searching Google.

The same goes for AMD and AMD graphics cards. Hard disks and the like are a bit more tricky but some manufacturers will list maximum operating temperatures.

Comment: There are many parameters shown in both applications but this time I am more concerned for temperature & fan speed. The hardware used in my desktop for which I am monitoring is Motherboard (ASUS M5A97), Processor (AMD FX 8320), Graphic Card (2GB Saphire 5450) and Hard Drive (WD Black 1TB).